# Icon replaced with CSS content() and ::before not shown in Firefox

Tags: css

I want to replace a text in a menu item with an icon via CSS. The Icon should then be clickable. I tried it with the following code and it looks good in Safari and Chrome. However Firefox displays "Home" instead of the image.

Does anybody know what the solution for Firefox is?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEQZLb

```
<ul id="menu-home" class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary">
  <li id="menu-item-1951" class="home menu-item ">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-17414" class="menu-item">
  <a href="link1">Link 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>

.nav-primary ul.menu > li a::before {
    visibility: visible;
}

.nav-primary ul.menu > li.home a::before {
  content: url('images/home_icon.jpg') no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  bottom:-2px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: From your fiddle i can't really see anything, could you make it a bit more precise? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `content` declaration contains a `no-repeat`, which appears to be a leftover from a previously-used `background` declaration. It needs to be removed:

```
content: url('images/home_icon.jpg');
position: relative;
bottom:-2px;
```

Additionally, although WebKit is known for egregious spec violations, this shouldn't work in Safari and Chrome just as it doesn't work on any other browser. There is really no reason for it to — [the grammar doesn't even expect a `no-repeat` token there.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-content) Even though [the recent rewrite of css-content](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-content/#inserting-replacing-content) offers a way to concatenate replaced content with arbitrary strings, even if it's implemented in Chrome, the `no-repeat` token here is clearly neither a string nor any of the valid values for `content`, and shouldn't be treated as such.

Also, if you're looking to *replace* the text with an image, you will probably need to position your image absolutely, over the text, and not relatively, since that simply inserts the image before the text. How you will implement this exactly depends on your layout, but I figured it was worth pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `no-repeat` problem mentioned by others, your CSS selectors are incorrect in several ways.

The refer to the class `.nav-primary` when there is no such class in your example, it is `.menu-primary`.  For the rest of this answer I will correct that mistake and use `menu-primary`.

`.menu-primary ul.menu` is asking for `ul.menu` inside a tag of class `menu-primary` and so will not match your HTML.  Instead, since the `ul` already has the class `menu-primary` simply refer to `ul.menu-primary`.

Putting that all together, its `ul.menu-primary > li a::before` and `ul.menu-primary > li.home a::before`.

Comment: +1 Good catch - I removed the erroneous selector from my answer since it focuses on the declarations anyway.

Comment: Thanks. This just happens when you do not completly paste your code. :/

Answer (score 1):

The `content` property doesn't include the `background-repeat` property.

You'll have to remove `no-repeat` in `content: url('images/home_icon.jpg') no-repeat;` for that rule to be valid. My guess is Chrome is allowing the error while FF is being strict about it.